# Javascript - pubnub api

Tags: javascript, pubnub

Javascript Newb - PHP programmer - Playing with this interesting API and trying to create function call (syntax needed) for this api.procedure;

```
pubnub.time(
    function(time){
       console.log(time)
                  }
           );
```

Goal - Have api procedure assign epoch time - when called (preferably) within a function, to be able to assign to concatenated message

1. Have tried assigning to var (i.e.; mynewvar = pubnub.time(... and the calling document.write procedure - results in unassigned.
2. Have tried assigning to a function (i.e.; Function mynewfunction () {pubnub.time(...and then call function results in same.

I am obviously missing some key point - I think this may be due to my poor understanding of the API procedure call and the object-dot-notation. Yes I am a procedural programmer from GWBASIC/PASCAL days. Have a field day colleagues, but be gentle :)

Comment: Just for clarification - This relates to the IIFE wrapping for local scope. Going to attempt to un-wrap and play with defining vars and procedure in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to do: You are trying to fetch the current time, and then include it as part of the message you publish? If so, this is how you'd do it:

```
var myTimeStamp = 0;

pubnub.time(
    function(time){

             pubnub.publish({
                 channel : "hello_world",
                 message : {"myTS":time, "myMsg":"This is my message!"}
             });
    }
);
```

On the subscriber side, you'd be able to convert that time into the format you prefer.

Is this what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
var pnub = {
   time: function () {
      return new Date().valueOf(); // Epoch time
   }
};

pnub.time(); // 1397940823979
```

As a PHP programmer turned JavaScript programmer, JavaScript took some getting used to.  Basically, make an object {}.  Assign methods to the object.  Call the methods.

I highly suggest reading Speaking Javascript by Axel Rauschmayer

Comment: In the original code on pubnub - the pubnub.x is a dot notation of the api socket/key call - here you pnub var does not dot.notate the original socket/api call - this should be an api generated timestamp correct?